# how to explode comma seperated array in for loop?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two comma separated arrays one for service ids and other for service quantities like this `1,2,3` for service ids and these are quantities `5,10,20` for service ids. Service id 1 have 5 quantity and id 2 have 10 and id 3 have 20 respectively. In this code i am getting services of ids but i have no idea how to set quantity against against those ids in loop and save. Hope you get my question.

I want to change `$result['service_quantity']` when loop works first time 5 comes then 10 then 20. so that i can save that.

```php
$checkRecord = Booking::where('id', $saveBooking->id)->get();

$allServicesArr = explode(",", $checkRecord[0]->services_ids);
$service = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allServicesArr); $i++) {

    $result = Service::find($allServicesArr[$i]);
    if ($result['id'] != '') {
        $service[$i]['id'] = $result['id'];
        $service[$i]['category_id'] = $result['category_id'];
        $service[$i]['event_id'] = $result['event_id'];
        $service[$i]['service_name'] = $result['service_name'];
        $service[$i]['service_kind'] = $result['service_kind'];
        $service[$i]['service_price'] = $result['service_price'];
        $service[$i]['service_quantity'] = $result['service_quantity'];
        $service[$i]['service_detail'] = $result['service_detail'];
    }

    $insertDate = new BookedServices();
    $insertDate->category_id = $result['category_id'];
    $insertDate->event_id = $result['event_id'];
    $insertDate->booking_id = $saveBooking->id;
    $insertDate->user_id = $userID;
    $insertDate->service_id = $result['id'];
    $insertDate->bs_name = $result['service_name'];
    $insertDate->bs_kind = $result['service_kind'];
    $insertDate->bs_price = $result['service_price'];
    $insertDate->bs_number = $result['service_number'];
    $insertDate->bs_detail = $result['service_detail'];
    $insertDate->save();
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$checkRecord = Booking::where('id', $saveBooking->id)->get();

$allServicesArr = explode(",", $checkRecord[0]->services_ids);
$allServicesQuantitiesArr = explode(",", $checkRecord[0]->services_quantity);

$service = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($allServicesArr); $i++) {

    $result = Service::find($allServicesArr[$i]);
    if ($result['id'] != '') {
        $service[$i]['id'] = $result['id'];
        $service[$i]['category_id'] = $result['category_id'];
        $service[$i]['event_id'] = $result['event_id'];
        $service[$i]['service_name'] = $result['service_name'];
        $service[$i]['service_kind'] = $result['service_kind'];
        $service[$i]['service_price'] = $result['service_price'];
        $service[$i]['service_number'] = $allServicesQuantitiesArr[$i];
        $service[$i]['service_detail'] = $result['service_detail'];
    }

    $insertDate = new BookedServices();
    $insertDate->category_id = $result['category_id'];
    $insertDate->event_id = $result['event_id'];
    $insertDate->booking_id = $saveBooking->id;
    $insertDate->user_id = $userID;
    $insertDate->service_id = $result['id'];
    $insertDate->bs_name = $result['service_name'];
    $insertDate->bs_kind = $result['service_kind'];
    $insertDate->bs_price = $result['service_price'];
    $insertDate->bs_number = $allServicesQuantitiesArr[$i];
    $insertDate->bs_detail = $result['service_detail'];
    $insertDate->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use built-in `array_combine` function for this purpose

```
$id=explode(",", "1,2,3");
$qty=explode(",", "5,10,15");

print_r(array_combine($id, $qty));
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 10
    [3] => 15
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$id=explode(",","1,2,3");
$qty=explode(",","5,10,15");

foreach($id as $index => $val){
    echo "id:".$val." Qty:".$qty[$index];    // id:1 Qty:5 
}
```

Comment: The second param of `explode` must be string